# Sending/receiving a newline with Javascript/C

Tags: javascript, c, websocket

```
char newline = '\n'; 
for ( i = 5 ; i < payload_length && payload[i] != newline ; i++ )
{
    username[i-5] = payload[i];
    username[i-4] = '\0';
}
```

This is part of some server code that I CANNOT modify. I'm writing the client side. I've tried the following

```
websocket.send("SEND "+name+"\n"+message);
websocket.send("SEND "+name+"\\n"+message);
websocket.send("SEND "+name+"\r\n"+message);
```

None work. It doesn't stop at the newline. If i set newline to '|' and then put in '|' in websocket.send then everything works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control in your c code what exactly arrives from the JS side of things by placing

```
printf ("chr arrived: %i %c \n", payload[i], payload[i]);
```

in your loop, which prints the numeric value of the current chr and the chr itself.

If you check the newline chr:

```
char newline = '\n';
printf ("chr arrived: %i %c \n", newline, newline);
```

output will be:

```
> ./test
chr arrived: 10

>
```

I guess what you send in your example are the characters `\`(92) and `n`(110) so i would sugest you try the following to specify you newline character in JS:

```
var newline = String.fromCharCode(10);
websocket.send("SEND "+name+newline+message);
```